# Unable to render HTML UL conditionally in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a list not more than 5 conditionally by checking the number of items and a "more" button. When I pass in 5 `li` items it renders it as text instead of HTML elements.

```js
let sectionCount = 0;
const MAX_COUNT_TO_SHOW = 5;
const getAssets = data => {
  let assets = "<ul>";
  let index = 0;
  for (var improperAsset of data) {
    if (index < MAX_COUNT_TO_SHOW) {
      assets += "<li>" + improperAsset + "</li>";
    }
    index++;
  }
  assets += "</ul>";
  console.log(assets);
  return <div>{assets}</div>;
};
const getSectionBody = info => {
  if (info.ic > MAX_COUNT_TO_SHOW) {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          {info.name} should be named as <b>{info.label}</b>
        </p>
        <i>
          <b>{info.ic}</b> instance(s) located for improper naming
        </i>
        {getAssets(info.data)}
        <div style={{ color: "blue" }} onClick={() => openDialog(info["data"])}>
          Show More
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          {info.name} should be named as <b>{info.label}</b>
        </p>
        <i>
          <b>{info.ic}</b> instance(s) located for improper naming
        </i>
        {getAssets(info.data)}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const isCollapsible = () => {
  if (sectionCount == 0) {
    sectionCount++;
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

const openDialog = useCallback(
  data => {
    setAssetsInfo(data);
    setClosed(false);
  },
  [setClosed]
);

return (
  <div style={{ margin: "0px 0px 10px 10px" }}>
    <Container fluid style={{ padding: "0px" }}>
      <Row>
        <Col sm={3}>
          <Button variant="primary">Customize</Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
    <Panel title={""}>
      {myData.map(info => {
        return (
          <Section
            key={uuid()}
            title={info.name + " " + info.tc + " (" + info.ic + ")"}
            collapsible
            expanded={isCollapsible()}
            initialCollapsed={true}
          >
            <Container fluid={true}>{getSectionBody(info)}</Container>
          </Section>
        );
      })}

      <MainDialog
        assetsInfo={assetsInfo}
        closed={closed}
        setClosed={setClosed}
      ></MainDialog>
    </Panel>
  </div>
);
```

[image]

Comment: Always, like **always** provide a [mre] in the form of https://CodeSandbox.io or something for React, please!

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Thank you for looking into my problem. The code that I posted uses internal libraries that I cannot publish eg: section, Container etc. This is why I did not gave a working example. I will try to provide reproducible code as much as possible where internal libs are not used.

Comment: Is there any simple PoC possible? Because it's really hard to debug without the necessary info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are passing in the data as a string rather than actual JSX elements. While you CAN do this it is very close to never being a good idea.

There are many ways to skin a cat but consider something like the following

```
const getAssets = data => {
  return 
    (
        <div>
            <ul>
              {data.slice(0,5).map((improperAsset) => (<li>{improperAsset}</li>))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};
```

If your "improperAsset" contains html and needs to be rendered as such, I would consider either moving these improper assets into separate components or using a library to handle HTML parsing otherwise you run serious risk of introducing cross site scripting vulnerabilities into your site.

Answer (score 0):

[FYI, that's how the minimal reproducible example may look like in that case.](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-roentgen-8iohk?file=/src/App.js) If you want to do that this way you can use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) but as mentioned earlier, this may expose your code to [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

```
return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: assets }}></div>;
```